# why database record is not retrieving properly on windows server 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have done one simple code. And I put the code on my local machine IIS. Then It's working properly. Even I check from other computer which is connected on lan.

**Here is my output from the local machine**

[image: IIS on Local machine]

Then I didn't change any single code. Then I copy the same file what i previously added on IIS in my local machine and I put it on my **Windows server 2012 R2**. **It retrieve some records, But it doesn't return all the records**

This is the output of **Windows server 2012 R2**
[image: Result of windows server 2012 r2 IIS]

**Note**

> Those Graph and Tables are records are based on database records.
>
> Then I Install visual studio 2012 and run the code on **Windows server 2012**, It doesn't show any error as well as no records on output **Without changing any single code**.
>
> I Checked whether database is connected or not. But it is connected. Because it's fetching the record on another page with exact result what I got on my local machine.
>
> Same thing happened on **windows server 2008 too.**

What will be the problem?

Comment: Today I asked totally 3 question. I didn't get any answer for any question. :(

Comment: Were you able to debug the code on Win Server 2012? Did you run the profiler on SQL Server and check what queries being executed on database for chart data? Did you compare the queries and their result with that of local machine run? Any differences do you see?

Comment: @chetanRanpariya What is profiler on sql server?. the local machine result and my sql result no difference. That is exact result